# Creating a thin line in PS CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I have an image about 1000 by 600px.

In Photoshop CS5 I could set the pixel width of the line to say, 3 px and drag the mouse from point A to B to create the line. Now, in CS6with the vector system, I cannot set the WEIGHT of the line to less that .35mm. I cannot create a thin line!!

Grrrr

Comment: maybe don't stroke it but fill it then zoom in really close and manually resize it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the shape tool. Just tested it in CC and you can set the line as small/thin as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

72ppi (typical screen resolution) is roughly 3 pixels per mm. Therefore a 1px stroke is .33mm, so (if my math is correct) your experience makes sense: you cannot have something smaller than a single pixel.